# Need to calculate SUM of certain values in one column depending on a value in different column in same row

Tags: excel, sum, excel-formula, pivot-table, excel-2013

I have data structure like following

```
No      Date       Name Vehicle     Finance
1001    01/04/2015  abc Activa       HDFC
1002    02/04/2015  abc Activa 125
1003    02/04/2015  abc Activa 3G    HDFC
1004    02/04/2015  abc Shine
1005    01/05/2015  abc Activa 3G
1006    01/05/2015  abc Dream Yuga
1007    02/05/2015  abc Unicorn 160
```

Now what I need is count of each vehicle for a certain month, say April. I was trying to do it something like this

```
=IF(MONTH('Sales Register'!C3)=4,COUNT('Sales Register'!A3:A5000),0)
```

But clearly it isn't the right way. How it can be done? Also if there is more complexity like I want to sum no of `Activa`s which are financed for a specific month by `HDFC`, how will it be done?

Comment: Hello, did you consider using pivot table?

Comment: I tried that but couldn't understand it as I have never used that before. Looked for some tutes but none were very explanatory. Still looking at few

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `No` is in A1, select A1:E8, INSERT > Tables, PivotTable. Click Existing Worksheet and for Location: G1, OK. Drag `Date` from Choose fields to add to report: to ROWS, drag `Vehicle` underneath `Date`. Drag `Finance` to COLUMNS and  `Name` into `Σ VALUES`.

PIVOTTABLE TOOLS > DESIGN > Layout Report Layout - Show in Tabular Form. Right-click ColumnG in the PT and uncheck Subtotal "Date". Right-click again and click Group... . Select Months and Years, OK.

Click the down arrow next to `Vehicle`, Label Filters, Contains..., enter `Activa`, OK.  Click the down arrow next to `Date`, click the tick next to  (Select all), and the empty box next to Apr, OK.

Result should look something like the following, though may depend slightly on Excel version and any remembered settings:

[image: SO28761768 example]

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this:

`=COUNT(B:B)-COUNTIF(B:B,"<"&F1)-COUNTIF(B:B,">"&G1)-1`

where `F1` is first day of the month, `G1` is last day of the month, minus one in the end is to deduct the header row. What this does, is, count number of all entries, deduct all entries before current month, deduct all entries after month, deduct header row.

Edit:
actually this would work too, enter following formula by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`:
`=SUM(IF(MONTH(B2:B8)=4,1,0))`

bear in mind if you range is quite extensive it will be quite slow as it is an array formula